# Axios post request with with credentials and body

Tags: node.js, curl, axios

I am trying to make the same request below in Axios, but it seems to not work. Does anyone have any idea?

```
curl -X POST -vu CLIENT_ID:CLIENT_SECRET http://localhost:9001/oauth/token -d "grant_type=password&username=user&password=password"
```

in Axios:

```
var reqData = "grant_type=password&username=username&password=password"

return axios.post("http://localhost:9001/oauth/token", reqData , {
      headers: {
        "Postman-Token": "4b7526c0-a204-4ad5-6194-49e0cd1bfd12",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
        "Authorization": "Basic "+base64.encode(CLIENT_ID + ':' + CLIENT_SECRET),
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
      }
    }).then(response => {
      console.log(response)
    return response})
```